# Calling a webservice via Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, rest

*Where am I going wrong?* I need to make a service call on a button click on whose 'OnClientClick' property, I've called xyz() for Ajax. But is is not working.

This is my JS:

```
function xyz() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod',
                data: "{ field1: '" + $("#txtfield1").val() + "' field2: '" + $("#txtfield2").val() + "' field3: '" + $("#dattimefield3").val() + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error: function () {
                    alert('Data null');
                },
                success: function () {
                    alert('Success');
                }
            });
        }
```

Here is my service that isn't being called by the Ajax call - the web service is supposed to be called. But it is not.

```
[HttpPost()]
    public String xyzmethod(string json)
    ...
```

Comment: any error messages? you're not calling an external website on a production server, are you?

Comment: is the function `xyz()` definitely being called?

Comment: Your `data` object isn't a valid JSON representation of an object

Comment: xyz() is definitely being called. alert 'error' pops up a message saying 'data null'. Is there a problem with the structure of the JSON that I've created?

Comment: @Andreas - What should I do to correct this?

Comment: Use a simple object and let jQuery do the rest for you (as @ZathrusWriter has written it in his answer)

Comment: @Andreas - I've already tried that. Still the same. An alert 'error' pops up a message saying 'data null'!

Comment: Add three parameters to your error handler and check them in the console.

Comment: @Andreas - And how do we do that? Bear with me please!

Comment: @Andreas - Did what you said!

error in: undefined
error:
undefined

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
function xyz() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod',
                data: {field1: $("#txtfield1").val(), field2: $("#txtfield2").val(), field3: $("#dattimefield3").val()},
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
                    for (var i in jqXHR) {
                        console.log(i + ' = ' + jqXHR[i]);
                    }
                },
                success: function () {
                    alert('Success');
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: @Zathurus Writer - Still the same!

Comment: Is JSON.stringify(json) of any use here?

Comment: you can even use `"field1="+$("#txtfield1").val()+"&field2="+$("#txtfield2").val()` and it would work, no need to stringify things... anyway, when you try my updated example, does it return *"error in: undefined error: undefined"* ?

Comment: check out my updated example and let me know what this outputs... please note that the output will be sent to your browser's console (I hope you're not using MSIE to test this, as I believe there is no console :D)

Comment: @Zathurus Writer - I am using Firefox. I do have a REST client installed. The following JSON, when POSTed to the URL gives me an HTTP 400 -----

{"field1":"value1","field2":"value2","field3":"2012-09-03T18:30:00.000Z"} ------ And, yes, still  'error -'

Comment: @Zathurus Writer - [12:50:24.122] responseText =  @ http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod.aspx:615
[12:50:24.123] status = 0 @ http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod.aspx:615
[12:50:24.123] statusText = error @ http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod.aspx:615

Comment: hmm, that sounds like a problem on the server side rather than on JavaScript side... I don't think I can help you with that part, since my knowledge of the technology used is non-existant, sorry

Comment: Zathurus Writer - a few problems have been resolved. I'll soon post the answer to this. Thanks for the help. It was very useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

syntax should be :

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod',
            data: { field1: $("#txtfield1").val(), field2: $("#txtfield2").val(), field3: $("#dattimefield3").val() },               
            error: function () {
                alert('Data null');
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
```

or you could build the data object before the call for simpler reading

```
var pars = {};
pars["textField1"] = $('#txtField1').val();
```

you can also do: (if you dynamic vars for example)

```
var myfield = "myfield2";
pars[myfield] = $('#'+myfield).val();
```

then:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:9210/xyzmodule/xyzmethod',
            data: pars,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function () {
                alert('Data null');
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
```

hope that helps

Comment: A prompt is displayed saying ' error in: undefined error: undefined'.